# Getting 'The channel dimension of the inputs (last axis) should be defined' error in LSTM layer even after defining the input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a simple project and trying to create a simple CNN RNN model using TensorFlow's Keras API. The model takes a sequence of images with a specified number of frames, width, height, and channel (RGB), and uses a combination of CNNs (ConvNet) and ConvLSTM layers to classify the sequence of images into different classes. However, I kept getting the above error when I try to run my model.

```
def create_model_cnnrnn(frames, width, height, channels, output):
            model = Sequential([
        # ConvNet
        TimeDistributed(
            MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,
                        input_shape=[height, width, channels]),
            input_shape=[frames, height, width, channels]
        ),
        TimeDistributed(GlobalAveragePooling2D()),

        # ConvLSTMs
        TimeDistributed(ConvLSTM2D(128, (3, 3), return_sequences=True)),
        BatchNormalization(),
        TimeDistributed(ConvLSTM2D(128, (3, 3))),

        # Feedforward
        Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
        Dropout(0.65),
        Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),
        Dropout(0.65),
        Dense(units=output, activation='softmax')
    ])

    return model
```

I tried adding the input shape to the layer

```
TimeDistributed(ConvLSTM2D(128, (3, 3), return_sequences=True), input_shape=(frames, 224, 224, 3)),
```

but I still get the error saying the  the channel dimension of the inputs is not defined in the input_shape argument of the ConvLSTM2D layer

```
ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs (last axis) should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: input_shape=(None,)
```

Could someone please advise where I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Here's my model.fit function:

```
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    validation_data=val_generator,
                    epochs=learn_epochs,
                    callbacks=[checkpoint_cb])
```

Thanks

Comment: It makes no sense to have a ConvLSTM after a global pooling layer, which removes height and width dimensions -- there is nothing to convolve over.

Comment: @xdurch0 thanks for pointing that out. Should I remove the global pooling layer? What would you advise be better for the task of handling temporal information in videos in this project? Thank you again

Comment: Well I guess you can either remove the global pooling, or keep it and use regular LSTM layers instead. You will probably need to try which works better. There are also other issues here, e.g. the ConvLSTM layers probably shouldn't be time-distributed (they already go over time) and you probably want a flatten layer before the dense layers...

Comment: As mentioned by @xdurch0, you don't need to use [ConvLSTM2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM2D#call-arguments) for this SimpleRNN model, also it takes 5d tensor as input which caused the above error. You can use [TimeDistributed](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/video#next_steps) as mentioned in this link for the same task. Thank you.